# Scala Playframework not all DB queries get executed

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm sending via HTTP Post Request a Json to my Playframework backend.

In my backend I validate the Json to a Model. After that, I want to save the entries in my Model to my DB.

```
   def parseJSON: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
       request =>
         Future {
           request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[MyModel] match {
             case JsSuccess(items, _) =>
               itemsToDBController.saveItems(items)
               Ok("Success")
             case JsError(err) =>
               println(err)
               BadRequest("Json Parse Error")
           }).getOrElse(BadRequest("Error"))
         }
     }
```

One Item consists out of several objects. To save all objects to my DB, I need to get some values. Therefore I'm using a for(..) yield(...):

```
   def saveItems(items: MyModel) = {
       items.SomeObject.map(obj => {
         if (obj.value1.isDefined &&
           obj.value2.isDefined ) {
           val result = for (
             value1Exists <- value1DTO.checkExists(obj.value1.name);
             value1Entry <- getOrCreateValue1(value1Exists, obj);
             value2Exists <- value2DTO.checkExists(obj.value2.name);
             value2Entry <- getOrCreateValue2(value1Exists, obj)
            ) yield(value1Entry, value2Entry)

           result.map({
             case (value1Entry, value2Entry) => {
               insertAllValue3(value1Entry, value2Entry)
               Future.successful()
             }
             case _ => Future.failed(new Exception("Not all entries defined"))
           })
         }
         else {
             Future.successful("Not all objects defined - skipping")
         }
       })
     }
```

My problem is, after all `result.map({...})` have started, my parseJSON Action `returns 200 - OK`. But not all relevant items get stored to my DB. It seems like after the `200 - OK` everything is stopped and it doesn't even throw an error.
I don't want to use Await.result or anything blocking in my Action.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting computations by calling `itemsToDBController.saveItems(items)` and then immediately return result with `Ok("Success")`. So exception may be thrown after request if completed.

To fix this issue you need to transform result of `itemsToDBController.saveItems` from `List[Future[T]]` to `Future[List[T]]` with help of `Future.sequence`. Then call `map` method on returned future. Call `recover` on this `Future` to find which error is thrown:

```
def parseJSON: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { request =>
  request.body.asJson
    .map(_.validate[MyModel] match {
      case JsSuccess(items, _) =>
        Future
          .sequence(itemsToDBController.saveItems(items))
          .map(_ => Ok("Success"))
          .recover {
            case e: Exception => BadRequest(e.getMessage())
          }

      case JsError(err) =>
        println(err)
        Future.successful(BadRequest("Json Parse Error"))
    })
    .getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("Error")))
}
```

**Update**

For running all inserts in one transaction you should combine `DBIOAction` instead of `Future`. For example you rewrite `checkExists(name)` as:

```
def checkExists(name: String): DBIO[Boolean] = {
  Objects.filter(obj => obj.name === name).exists
}
```

`getOrCreateValue(exists, obj)` as:

```
def getOrCreateValue(exists: boolean, obj: Object): DBIO[Object] = {
  if (exists) {
    Objects.filter(o => o.name === name).result.head
  } else {
    (Objects returning Objects.map(_.id) into ((o, id) => o.copy(id = Some(id)))) += obj
  }
}
```

Now you can run it in single transaction in the following way:

```
def saveItems(items: MyModel) = {
  val insertActions = items.SomeObject.map(obj => {
    if (obj.value1.isDefined && obj.value2.isDefined) {
      val result = for {
        value1Exists <- value1DTO.checkExists(obj.value1.name);
        value1Entry <- getOrCreateValue1(value1Exists, obj);
        value2Exists <- value2DTO.checkExists(obj.value2.name);
        value2Entry <- getOrCreateValue2(value1Exists, obj)
      } yield (value1Entry, value2Entry)

      result.flatMap({
        case (value1Entry, value2Entry) => {
          insertAllValue3(value1Entry, value2Entry) // This also returns instance of `DBIOAction`
        }
        case _ =>
          DBIO.failed(new Exception("Not all entries defined"))
      })
    } else {
      DBIO.successful("Not all objects defined - skipping")
    }
  })
  db.run(DBIO.sequence(inserActions).transactionally)
}
```

For mo info how to work with DBIO actions check this official [docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/dbio.html#database-io-actions)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your solution does not completly fix the issue. `.recover´is not available here. With your solution I have the wrong return value. I need a `Future[Result] ` but I got `Future[Equals]` as return type of my Action. Return type of `saveItems()` is `Seq[Future[Object]]` just as little hint.

Comment: Thanks. when I remove the recover it works better now. I got this `Task slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@c99e7c3 rejected from slick.util.AsyncExecutor$$anon$2$$anon$1@2baaeb06[Running, pool size = 20, active threads = 20, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 1056]`

Comment: Seems like you send a lot of sql queries at once and slick thread pool is overflowed. You need to check thread pool configuration

Comment: Thanks I have changed the settings now we got closer to the solution. At the moment we have one single issue open. We got race contions because of the threads: `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'ibm' for key 'name'`

Is there a way to synchronize the inserts? Thanks

Comment: I think running all checks and inserts in one transaction may help but it would require a lot of refactoring in `saveItems` method. You could read about transaction management in slick here - http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/dbio.html#transactions. I'll update my answer with concept later.

Comment: Hi Valerii, I've refactored our code and have achieved some improvements. But we still get race conditions due to parallel execution or queued transactions. Therefore we get a BadRequest response.

Comment: Hi @Felix. Could you update your question with refactored code?

Comment: Hi @Valerii may you have a look at the answer beneath of Ari Friso? Thanks in advance