# Play Framework slick stops DB actions without error

Tags: mysql, playframework, slick

My questions is based on this previous one: [Scala Playframework not all DB queries get executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522195/scala-playframework-not-all-db-queries-get-executed/)

The code is working fine for smaller files. But for larger files (> 500.000 lines of JSON) it stops without any problem. For the same file it always stops at the same JSON entry. Note: the process of takes a lot of time.

I tried my app on my local machine or on a server and a local MySQL DB or an AWS DB. I also tried different slick configs and JVM Xms, Xmx and Xss values without any different result.

This is my slick config:

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://url:3306/db"
        user = "user"
        password = "password"
        queueSize = 1000
        numThreads = 50
        connectionTimeout = 30000
        maximumPoolSize = 100
        cacheServerConfiguration=true
        rewriteBatchedStatements=true
        useServerPrepStmts=true
        cachePrepStmts=true
        prepStmtCacheSize=500
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=50000
      }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion how I can improve my code? As I mentioned If I reduce the file size, everything works fine. How can I speed up my DB inserts or increase cache size further?

Thanks in advance!

---- Update ----

Insert Code: `itemSeq` is my validated JSON (this works fine).

```
import javax.inject._
import play.Logger
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}
import slick.jdbc.{JdbcProfile, TransactionIsolation}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

import

... // DTOs


@Singleton
class ExampleController @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider, cc: ControllerComponents,
                                  otherRestController: OtherRestController,

... // DTOs
) extends AbstractController(cc) with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {

  import profile.api._


  def insertEntries(allEntries: exampleModel): Future[Seq[Any]] = {

    val insertActions = allEntries.seqEntries.map(itemOfSeq => {
      if (itemOfSeq.pbDate.isDefined &&
        itemOfSeq.value1.descr.isDefined && itemOfSeq.value1.descr.get.descr_data.isDefined && itemOfSeq.value1.descr.get.descr_data.get.head.value.isDefined &&
        itemOfSeq.value2.isDefined
        && itemOfSeq.value1.aff.value3.value3_data.nonEmpty && itemOfSeq.value1.aff.value3.value3_data.head.value4.value4_data.nonEmpty) {

        val pbDateSql: Date = new Date(format.parse(itemOfSeq.pbDate.get).getTime)
        val modDateSql: Date = new Date(format.parse(itemOfSeq.modDate.get).getTime)

        val result = for (
          value3Entry <- value3DTO.getOrCreate(Value3_Model(None, itemOfSeq.value1.aff.value3.value3_data.head.name));
          value1Exists <- value1DTO.checkIfEntryExists(itemOfSeq.value1.meta_data.ID);
          value1Entry <- value1DTO.getOrCreate(Value1_Model(None, itemOfSeq.value1.meta_data.ID, value3Entry.value3Id.get, itemOfSeq.value1.descr.get.descr_data.get.head.value.get,
            pbDateSql, modDateSql), value1Exists);
          value4Entry <- value4DTO.getOrCreate(Value4_Model(None, value3Entry.value3Id.get, itemOfSeq.value1.aff.value3.value3_data.head.value4.value4_data.head.v4value1))
        ) yield (value1Exists, value1Entry, value4Entry)

        result.flatMap({
          case (value1Exists, value1Entry, value4Entry) => {
            if (!value1Exists) {
              otherRestController.checkAllMatches(itemOfSeq)

              DBIO.sequence(itemOfSeq.value1.values5.value5_data.map(val5 => {

                var value5 = Value5_Model(None, val5.v5val1, val5.v5val2)
                if (value5.v5val2.contains("http")) {
                  value5 = Value5_Model(None, val5.v5val2, val5.v5val1)
                }

                value5DTO
                  .getOrCreate(value5)
                  .flatMap(v1v5 => {
                    value1Value5DTO.getOrCreate(∂
                      Value1_Value5_Model(value1Entry.value1Id.get,
                      v1v5.v5Id.get)
                    ).andThen(DBIO.sequence(val5.values6.map(val6 => {
                      Value6DTO.getOrCreate(Value6_Model(None, val6)).flatMap(v6 => {
                        value5value6DTO.getOrCreate(Value5_Value6_Model(v1v5.v5Id.get, v6.v6Id.get))
                      })
                    })))
                  })
              })
              ).>>(DBIO.sequence(itemOfSeq.value1.aff.value3.value3_data.head.value4.value4_data.head.value7.value7_data.map(val7 => {
                value7DTO.getOrCreate(Value6_Model(None, value4Entry.value4Id.get, val7.v4val1)).flatMap(v7 => {
                  Value1Value7DTO.getOrCreate(Value1_Value7_Model(value1Entry.value1Id.get, v7.value7Id.get))
                })
              }))
              ).>>(if (itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.isDefined && itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.isDefined) {
                for {
                  i <- value10DTO
                    .getOrCreate(Value10_Model(None, value1Entry.value1Id.get))
                  v8 <- value8DTO.getOrCreate(
                    Value8_Model(None, i.value10Id.get, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val1,
                      itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val2, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val3)
                  )
                  v9 <- baseMetricV3DTO.getOrCreate(
                    Value9_Model(None, i.value10Id.get, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val1,
                      itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val2, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val3)
                  )

                } yield (i, v8, v9)
              }
              else if (itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.isDefined && itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.isEmpty) {
                for {
                  i <- value10DTO
                    .getOrCreate(Value10_Model(None, value1Entry.value1Id.get))
                  v8 <- value8DTO.getOrCreate(
                    Value8_Model(None, i.value10Id.get, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val1,
                      itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val2, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val3)
                  )
                } yield (i, v8)
              }
              else {
                for {
                  i <- value10DTO
                    .getOrCreate(Value10_Model(None, value1Entry.value1Id.get))
                  v9 <- baseMetricV3DTO.getOrCreate(
                    Value9_Model(None, i.value10Id.get, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val1,
                      itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val2, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val3)
                  )
                } yield (i, v9)
              })
            } else {
              DBIO.sequence(itemOfSeq.value1.values5.value5_data.map(val5 => {
                var value5 = Value5_Model(None, val5.v5val1, val5.v5val2)
                if (value5.v5val2.contains("http")) {
                  value5 = Value5_Model(None, val5.v5val2, val5.v5val1)
                }
                value5DTO
                  .getOrCreate(value5)
                  .flatMap(v1v5 => {
                    value1Value5DTO.getOrCreate(
                      Value1_Value5_Model(value1Entry.value1Id.get,
                        v1v5.v5Id.get)
                    ).andThen(DBIO.sequence(val5.values6.map(val6 => {
                      Value6DTO.getOrCreate(Value6_Model(None, val6)).flatMap(v6 => {
                        value5value6DTO.getOrCreate(Value5_Value6_Model(v1v5.v5Id.get, v6.v6Id.get))
                      })
                    })))
                  })
              })
              ).>>(if (itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.isDefined && itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.isDefined) {
                for {
                  i <- value10DTO
                    .getOrCreate(Value10_Model(None, value1Entry.value1Id.get))
                  v8 <- value8DTO.getOrCreate(
                    Value8_Model(None, i.value10Id.get, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val1,
                      itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val2, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val3)
                  )
                  v9 <- baseMetricV3DTO.getOrCreate(
                    Value9_Model(None, i.value10Id.get, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val1,
                      itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val2, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val3)
                  )

                } yield (i, v8, v9)
              }
              else if (itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.isDefined && itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.isEmpty) {
                for {
                  i <- value10DTO
                    .getOrCreate(Value10_Model(None, value1Entry.value1Id.get))
                  v8 <- value8DTO.getOrCreate(
                    Value8_Model(None, i.value10Id.get, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val1,
                      itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val2, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value8.get.value8_data.v8val3)
                  )
                } yield (i, v8)
              }
              else {
                for {
                  i <- value10DTO
                    .getOrCreate(Value10_Model(None, value1Entry.value1Id.get))
                  v9 <- baseMetricV3DTO.getOrCreate(
                    Value9_Model(None, i.value10Id.get, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val1,
                      itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val2, itemOfSeq.value2.get.value9.get.value9_data.v9val3)
                  )
                } yield (i, v9)
              })
            }
          }
          case _ => DBIO.failed(new Exception("Not all entries defined"))
        })
      }
      else {
        DBIO.successful("Not all objects defined - skipping")
      }
    })
    db.run(DBIO.sequence(insertActions).transactionally.withTransactionIsolation(TransactionIsolation.Serializable))
  }
}
```

getOrCreate example-Code:

```
def getOrCreate(model: Value_Model): DBIO[Value_Model] = {
    for {
      exists <- valueTable.filter(b => b.v1val1 === model.v1val1).exists.result
      entry <- if (exists) {
        valueTable.filter(b => b.v1val1 === model.v1val1)
          .map(b => (b.v1val1, b.v1val2, b.v1val3)
          .update((model.v1val1, model.v1val2, model.v1val3))
          .>>(valueTable.filter(b => b.v1val1 === model.v1val1).result.head)
      } else
        (valueTable
          returning valueTable.map(_.value1Id)
          into ((params, id) => params.copy(value1Id = Some(id)))
          ) += model
    } yield entry
  }
```

This whole code runs for smaller files/`seqEntries` without any problem.
Today I've tested it again with > 10000 `itemOfSeq` and > 100MB file size.
Validation etc. works fine.
During my testing I also tried the standard slick config, but this had no effect on the result also:

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://url:3306/db"
        user = "user"
        password = "password"
        connectionPool = disabled
      }
    }
}
```

It always stopped at the same `itemOfSeq`, without an error or warning.

I've logged `slick.jdbc` like following:

```
<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.parameter" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.benchmark" level="DEBUG"/>
```

The log file doesn't contain any error/warining either.

The application remains accessible, even though the DB insert process seems stopped or killed.

Hope this code helps you for further debugging. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you stay stops without any problem, is the process being killed somehow? Is MySQL dropping the connection? Need to do some digging to find out if it's a MySQL issue, or a framework/jdbc issue.

Comment: So I checked at AWS the Open connections and they are still open. And the process is not getting killed, I can call other Routes of my Play App and they still work.

Comment: Do some debugging into the JSON. Why is it stopping on that line? Is it a conflict in the database due to some ID?

Comment: Well like in the linked question I validate the json and I checked the json entry manually w/o any abnormality. If an ID would match with the entries in my DV I would do an getOrUpdare on that ID.

Comment: Would be helpful to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @FrankerZ I've posted some example code. Thanks in advance.